# How to fix error code 9 in subprocess.wait() started by PuLP

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to solve an optimization problem where different data sets are used as input. For most of the sets my programm utilizing the PuLP libary with the coin-or CBC solver works just fine. But for one data set in particular it crashes. The error raised is the following:
https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/746f35cd23711b01237c83850ef1dabb0889da83/pulp/solvers.py#L1445

I then printed the returncode from cbc.wait() from the subprocess python module which was -9 corresponding to: 
    `EBADF            9      /* Bad file number */` in unix.

Well that wasn't all that helpful, was it?

I then took a look at what differs for this data set compared to the others. 
Structurally they seem to be the same. (sparse, no Nan). For clarification the low rank approximation of the data set is used to set the inequality constraints in the optimization problem.

I also changed the solvers output to true to maybe deduct the problem from there. But it seems to work normally and then just throws the above error.

```
command line - cbc /tmp/e2a9e3cf978546a3bd5d4074c9bf99cb-pulp.mps threads 30 sec 36000 branch printingOptions all solution /tmp/e2a9e3cf978546a3bd5d4074c9bf99cb-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 297 COLUMNS
At line 43807 RHS
At line 44100 BOUNDS
At line 44398 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 292 rows, 149 columns and 43212 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
threads was changed from 0 to 30
seconds was changed from 1e+100 to 36000
Continuous objective value is 0 - 0.06 seconds
Cgl0004I processed model has 290 rows, 148 columns (147 integer (0 of which binary)) and 42920 elements
Cbc0031I 3 added rows had average density of 148
Cbc0013I At root node, 3 cuts changed objective from 0 to 0.0042535435 in 100 passes
Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Probing) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 3.386 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 1 (Gomory) - 1461 row cuts average 148.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 3.320 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 2 (Knapsack) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.022 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 3 (Clique) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.001 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 4 (MixedIntegerRounding2) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.380 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0014I Cut generator 5 (FlowCover) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.093 seconds - new frequency is -100
Cbc0010I After 0 nodes, 1 on tree, 1e+50 best solution, best possible 0.0042535435 (14.64 seconds)
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 1.0374824 found by rounding after 3265 iterations and 1 nodes (15.94 seconds)
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 1.0374824 found by heuristic after 3264 iterations and 0 nodes (15.94 seconds)
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 1.0218801 found by rounding after 14797 iterations and 346 nodes (147.81 seconds)
Cbc0012I Integer solution of 1.0218801 found by heuristic after 15786 iterations and 375 nodes (147.81 seconds)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 273, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 219, in main_for_cleaned_and_aggregated_data

  File "main.py", line 88, in run_all_milp_variants
    solution = milp_solver.get_or_create(data=data, output_dir=save_dir)
  File "/home/ubuntu/milp/milp_solver.py", line 202, in get_or_create
    milp_result = __run(data=data, reg_param=reg_param, type=type, output_dir=output_dir)
  File "/home/ubuntu/milp/milp_solver.py", line 111, in __run
    prob.solve(pp.solvers.COIN_CMD(threads=30, maxSeconds=36000, msg=1))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pulp/pulp.py", line 1671, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pulp/solvers.py", line 1367, in actualSolve
    return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pulp/solvers.py", line 1430, in solve_CBC
    self.path)
pulp.solvers.PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while trying to execute cbc
```

If somebody has a clue what is happening here please elaborate. I am at the end of my code digging journey with my limited experience on sub-processing tasks.

Comment: I suspect CBC crashed (or was killed). First I would try is to run with 1 thread. 30 threads is probably overkill.

Comment: I am going to try a lower threadcount. Any Idea what the reason is that CBC crashed?

Comment: No. You might be able to find out more by letting cbc write out a core file.